# Any airbag problems when removing seats?

Tags: interior

Car is a civic vti 1999.

I heard that if you remove seats on some cars  the airbag may go off because it’s connected or something.  I want to remove my seats for cleaning.  Can I just directly remove them without any problem?

Answer (score 3):

Well it depends, in cases where you have ODS (occupant detection systems) then it will store codes from being unhooked. With the key OFF the airbag module should have no power and The airbag itself should not go off but crazier things have happened so anytime you are working with airbag components the safest thing to do is always unhook your battery. I am not sure on your Civic exactly but if you have a passenger airbag then you should disconnect your battery before unhooking the ODS under the seat just to prevent storing the DTC's in the system.

Comment: Warning* Disconnected battery will not prevent air bag deployment. Airbag controller has a super capacitor that can deploy the bag long after the battery is disconnected.

Comment: Also, it's a good idea to wait about 10 minutes after disconnecting the battery to work with the airbags. This give the caps a bit of time to discharge but you still have to be cautious

Comment: +1 for the trouble code risk.  This is probably your biggest headache and is enough of an argument to disconnect the battery.  I unhooked a "air bag disabled light" next to a radio once and it set a trouble code that required a dealer-level diag tool to clear.